# Can I get OS X Dictation to work in Lotus Notes?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I really like enhanced (offline) dictation in OS X 10.9, and use it a lot. I'd like to use it within [Lotus Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/category/messaging/) (9.0.1), but unfortunately double-pressing the "Fn" key when I'm composing an email doesn't seem to do anything.

Do applications have to do something special to support dictation? Is there anything I can do to get additional applications such as Lotus Notes to support dictation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it doesn't work at this time. I tried looking for a matching SPR but I couldn't find one.

So I have created SPR SODY9GMBDH so that development can investigate further. Do not treat this as a final answer though (as someone may have worked around it).

Comment: What is an SPR?

Comment: "Software Problem Report". Details the issue for development to investigate. Disclosure: I work for IBM.

Comment: Simon, so do I! I'd never heard of that before. Thanks for logging one.